# nsurlsessiond hogging on internet when running iOS simulator

Tags: iphone, icloud

I try to stay as far away from iCloud as possible. I've **not** signed into iCloud on my mac.

But for some reason, `nsurlsessiond`, the service associated with iCloud seems to be hogging my network connection in the background whenever I open up the iOS simulator.

I noticed that a family member backed up their iPad onto the common iCloud account; ~ 4GB.

Is that backup causing this annoying bandwidth-hogging? I'm not even signed into my apple account in the simulator.

Besides, why would an iPad backup be synced with an iPhone simulator anyway?

Is iCloud really just designed this badly, or is am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either one of these will fix it.

```
rm /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/libexec/nsurlsessiond
```

```
rm /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/libexec/nsurlsessiond
```

If you can't find the `nsurlsession` binary at these places, I'd suggest you do a search using Finder, or grab the path using `htop`

Comment: For me, the file was at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/libexec/nsurlsessiond` (`Developer/Library` instead of `Library/Developer`).

Comment: @dev-aggarwal It worked